# icecast fallback with redundancy

Tags: fallback, icecast, internet-radio

How can I setup icecast config file fallbacks as per scenario below

1 mount point "listen.mp3" where the listeners would connect to. this mount point will fallback to "main.mp3"

1 main point "main.mp3" which will fallback to either of the following 2 sub streams ("primary.mp3" and "secondary.mp3") that are similar for redundancy purposes

When the listeners connect to "listen.mp3", they would **automatically fall back to "main.mp3" and again fall to any of the 2 available sub streams "primary.mp3" and "secondary.mp3".

if "primary.mp3" is not available then the listeners will be moved to "secondary.mp3", 
if "secondary.mp3" fails then the listeners will be moved to "primary.mp3"

Currently, my config file is set up as above but with only 1 stream point "main.mp3" see config below

```
<mount>
   <mount-name>/listen.mp3</mount-name>
   <fallback-mount>/main.mp3</fallback-mount>
   <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
</mount>
```

**Note that I must have the "listen.mp3" as a mount point where the listeners connect to. i won't state the reason so not to complicate things for this question.

UPDATE:

Will this do the trick?

```
<mount>
   <mount-name>/listen.mp3</mount-name>
   <fallback-mount>/main.mp3</fallback-mount>
   <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
</mount>

<mount>
   <mount-name>/main.mp3</mount-name>
   <fallback-mount>/primary.mp3</fallback-mount>
   <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
</mount>

<mount>
   <mount-name>/primary.mp3</mount-name>
   <fallback-mount>/secondary.mp3</fallback-mount>
   <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
</mount>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick after testing...

```
<mount>
   <mount-name>/listen.mp3</mount-name>
   <fallback-mount>/main.mp3</fallback-mount>
   <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
</mount>

<mount>
   <mount-name>/main.mp3</mount-name>
   <fallback-mount>/primary.mp3</fallback-mount>
   <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
</mount>

<mount>
   <mount-name>/primary.mp3</mount-name>
   <fallback-mount>/secondary.mp3</fallback-mount>
   <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
</mount>
```